# making a query to group things by IP

Tags: mysql

I've a query question and want to know iff this is possible whit a query.
The DB where I've the question about look something like this:

```html
-------------------------------------------
id  |  name       |        IP      |   nr
-------------------------------------------
 1  | Fleet-1234  | 192.168.52.254 | 1234
 5  | Boat-4567   | 192.168.52.256 | NULL
 9  | Boat-4565   | 192.168.52.250 | NULL
10  | Boat-4547   | 192.168.52.252 | NULL
13  | Fleet-6663  | 192.168.44.256 | 6663
18  | Boat-2345   | 192.168.44.145 | NULL
56  | Boat-2345   | 192.168.44.14  | NULL
60  | Boat-1111   | 192.168.44.15  | NULL
```

The result I was hoping for is :

```html
-------------------------------------------
id  |  name       |        IP      |   nr
-------------------------------------------
 1  | Fleet-1234  | 192.168.52.254 | 1234
 5  | Boat-4567   | 192.168.52.256 | 1234
 9  | Boat-4565   | 192.168.52.250 | 1234
10  | Boat-4547   | 192.168.52.252 | 1234
13  | Fleet-6663  | 192.168.44.256 | 6663
18  | Boat-2345   | 192.168.44.145 | 6663
56  | Boat-2345   | 192.168.44.14  | 6663
60  | Boat-1111   | 192.168.44.15  | 6663
```

What i think I need to do is:
-compare first 3 octets of IP (the are the same in the same "fleet")
-iff compare is found the use "nr" colum from the Fleet-XXXX in the same "group"

I realy don't know iff this is possible and how to do this.
Is there somebody who can help me whit this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9088e5/8) :

```
SELECT 
    t0.id
    , t0.name
    , t0.IP
    , t1.nr
FROM your_table t0
INNER JOIN (SELECT LEFT(IP, LENGTH(IP) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(IP))) AS shortened_IP, MAX(nr) AS nr FROM your_table GROUP BY 1) t1
ON LEFT(IP, LENGTH(IP) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(IP))) = t1.shortened_IP;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i dont "set" anything whit this .
I need to "set" the "boat" "nr" colum whit the "fleet" "nr"
Or I do it wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a substr and a group by

```
select substr(IP, LOCATE('.', REVERSE(IP))+1, 3) as ip_base, count(*)
from your_table 
group by ip_base;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i dont "set" anything whit this and got only a count from a group when i tried your proposal.

I need to "set" the "boat" "nr" colum whit the "fleet" "nr"